# XML to mongodb JSON. Node JS and Angular JS to for Web application.

Tags: angularjs, json, xml, mongodb, nodes

Scenarios :

We have bunch of XML files stored in SQL server table as BLOB column. There is no interface to view XML file details. 
These are response files from external source. 
My customer wants to convert into RDBM tables.

Currently part of the implementation is completed. They are reading XML from SQL server using XQuery/XPath and SSIS ETL packages and stored into SQL Server.

Instead I am planning to propose to convert XMLs into JSON format and store into MongoDB. This will help to manage growing database size compare to MS SQL (Based on my reading mongodb better).

Use mongodb collection metadata (nested Sub documents elements and attributes) to show filters on web application so that user can choose details to views on screen.
I am planning to use mongo db, node js and angular js. I am very new to these technologies.

1. Is it make sense to use MongoDB, Mongoose, node js and angulare js. If not any additional platform i can think.
2. Do I need to define data model for each of the XML type. If yes, every time if there is new element added into XML I will have modify the model/schema.  
   My understanding is extra elements added/deleted into JSON, MongoDB will take care which is not the case relational database. I don't know in detail yet.
3. Can I access the meta data of  model dynamically on web application for filtering records.

In this case I have only read operation. XML format will be changed rarely. It is pulled from external interface.

Any expert opinions about my direction.

Thanks.